# AWS API Gateway MTLS client

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, ssl-client-authentication, aws-alb

Does anyone know if the following feature request is now available on AWS or possible work around?

**[AWS API Gateway MTLS client auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456287/aws-api-gateway-mtls-client-auth)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS API Gateway MTLS client auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456287/aws-api-gateway-mtls-client-auth)

Comment: I tried to comment on that but stackoverflow did not allow me (says I must have some level of badge before I can comment).. Hence the reason for me creating this topic.

Answer (score 2):

This is still not available. If you need MTLS auth you would need to build this in a proxy layer in front of API Gateway.